# Architecture to represent multiple level grouping in .net

Tags: .net, architecture, grouping

I have a list of key-value documents coming out of Lucene.net, and i'd like to be able to group them depending on various values, depending on user input. So basically i have the following list

```
Doc#1 - Weight:10;Size:20;ExpiresIn:90days
Doc#2 - Weight:10;Size:30;ExpiresIn:90days
Doc#3 - Weight:10;Size:20;ExpiresIn:30days
Doc#4 - Weight:10;Size:20;ExpiresIn:30days
```

and i want the user to tell me: group this on size then weight which would produce the following

```
Size: 20
 Weight: 10
  Count: 3
  Doc#1, Doc#3, Doc#4
Size: 30
 Weight: 10
  Count: 1
  Doc#2
```

But he could as well tell me to group on ExpiresIn:

```
ExpiresIn: 90Days
 Count: 2
 Doc#1, Doc#2
ExpiresIn: 30Days
 Count: 2
 Doc#3, Doc#4
```

My problem is not really one of speed (though it will certainly be present in case of huge datasets) but rather one of architecture. I'd like to know how i could represent the various entities i have:

- a leaf-type node containing the list of docs (and their count, trivial) (*the leaf node in the first example*)
- a just-above-leaf node that contains a list of leaves (*Weight in the first example*)
- a top-to-n-2 node that contains a list of nodes (*size in the first example*)

I've tried starting from a common abstract node that would contain a list of generic nodes: however this approach kind of crumbles as soon as i try to inject a document from the top since each node doesn't know its own context and haven't got a clue as to what it's supposed to create after him.

```
Public MustInherit Class Node(Of T)
    Implements IEnumerable(Of T)

    Private InnerValue As String
    Private InnerGrouping As String
    Protected InnerData As New List(Of T)

    MustOverride Sub AddGroupingElement(element As LuceneSearchResultsInfo)
End Class

Public Class LeafNode
    Inherits Node(Of LuceneSearchResultsInfo)

    Public Overrides Sub AddGroupingElement(element As LuceneSearchResultsInfo)
        InnerData.Add(element)
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class CommonNode
    Inherits Node(Of CommonNode)

    Public Overrides Sub AddGroupingElement(element As LuceneSearchResultsInfo)
        Dim InterestedNode = InnerData.FirstOrDefault(Function(n) n.Value = element.Field(Grouping))
        If (InterestedNode Is Nothing) Then
            InterestedNode = New CommonNode ' argh, i'm stuck, i don't know the rest of the context
        End If

    End Sub
End Class
```

I was thinking about storing a simple dictionnary with the full path to the document stored as key. It's simpler but not really as pleasant to work with as a dedicated structure would be. So any ideas welcome :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nodes can't be inserted at an arbitrary level in such a structure. (Your tree is a representation of a list of documents grouped by attributes. Inserting at arbitrary level means loss of attributes consistency, as if you add a single cell to a table, instead of a row representing a documents with full attributes set.)  So, items insertions and deletions should be maintained by tree itself.

Consider such class structure (C#, as I'm not good in VB syntax):

```
class TableAsTree
{
    GroupingNode Root;  

    public void Insert(LuceneSearchResultsInfo sr)
    {
        /* Recursively insert */
        InsertToGroup(Root, sr); /* - root node would store all items */

    }

    public void InsertToGroup(GroupingNode node, LuceneSearchResultsInfo sr)
    {
        node.Documents.Add(sr.Document);
        //sample: Find "Weight" group with key = weight of current doc.
        var childGroup = ChildGroups.First(g => g.GroupKey == sr.Fields(g.GroupFieldName)); /*create if there is no group for the value*/
        InsertToGroup(childGroup, sr);
    }
}

class GroupingNode<TDocument>
{   
    string GroupKey;                    /* Group key value = 1 or 2 or 3 in (Size=1,2,3), no meaning for root */
    string GroupFieldName;              /* Group field name (Size), null for root */
    List<TDocument> Documents;          /* Documents at the level - you can add them for each level, or of the level before the last one */ 
    List<GroupingNode> ChildGroups;
}
```

Using it you'll be able to acquire the list of docs at each of grouping levels.

Comment: After letting the problem mature a bit, i find out that what i'm asking is not something that i can represent with a tree; however mikalai brings a nice solution if we want to get the same functionalities at all levels.